# Unable to start mysql after moving it to USB memory stick

Tags: raspbian, mysql

To have more room for databases, I copied /var/lib/mysql  to  /media/usb/mysql

To copy them, I had to change their owner and group, so they are now showing

/var/lib/mysql shows 755 mysql:mysql
/media/usb/mysql shows 755 pi:pi

I changed the datatdir in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Rebooted and restarted mysql service.

Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
journalctl -xn shows "No journal files were found."

systemctl status mysql.service shows --- â mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-11-24 09:29:27 GMT; 45s ago
  Process: 1635 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

the mysql service starts OK if I change datatdir in /etc/mysql/my.cnf back to /var/lib/mysql

Does /media/usb/mysql pi:pi need to be mysql:mysql?

I've tried CHOWN in various ways but it always comes back with 'Operation not permitted' - even under 'SUDO -i'

I'm stuck now, any advice much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your USB stick most likely is FAT32 formatted. FAT filesystems do not support user/group settings nor do they support the usual access rights settings. You have to reformat the stick with a filesystem which does or put all the data you need into a filesystem-in-a-file and mount that one.